# Upload mp4 with progress using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have previously uploaded files to a presigned URL by doing the following:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];
[self.httpSessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[self.httpSessionManager PUT:operation.relativeURLString parameters:@{@"data": data} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    [self handleResponse:responseObject forSuccessfulOperation:operation];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    [self handleError:error forFailedOperation:operation];
}];
```

But the need to track uploading progress made me change this into:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:operation.relativeURLString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data
                                name:@"data"
                            fileName:@"video.mp4"
                            mimeType:@"video/mp4"];
} error:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [self.httpSessionManager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        [self handleResponse:responseObject forSuccessfulOperation:operation];
    }
    else
    {
        [self handleError:error forFailedOperation:operation];
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

This seems to upload the file successfully until I try to play it. It has the correct file size, but the file seems to be broken since it will not play. Am I misinterpreting how to use multipartFormRequest? I have come to understand that using NSStream or a memory mapped file instead of passing along NSData is preferable, but to my knowledge, this shouldn't be the cause of my issue, but a mere performance tweak.

Comment: You were uploading a NSData object so use uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:progress:completionHandler: instead

Comment: I must not be a very smart man. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielLarsson Your problem solved?